# Java class variable number

Tags: java, class, variables

I'm learning java and now I have this question.

I created a class named "Driver" and it will hold a driver's information (name and birthday).

To create a new driver I just need to do:

```
Driver d1 = new Driver("John", "01/01/1980");
```

Now imagine I have a program that will read x drivers information from a file. How can I create x drivers?

My problem is that i'm thinking I need x variables for x drivers but variables can only be hard-coded by me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use an array or collection (`List` or `Set`):

```
List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
drivers.add(new Driver(..));
drivers.add(new Driver(..));
```

When reading from a file you usually use a loop. So on each iteration add the object to the list.

Comment: I've never worked with collections so I ask another question. Using that List thing, how can I access a specific driver?

Comment: check the javadoc. drivers.get(index) gives you the index'th element

Answer (score 2):

What you need, essentially, is to read each driver one by one, and store them in a *collection*. There are multiple collection classes in Java, but `ArrayList` should do just fine in your case:

```
ArrayList<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();

Driver d1 = new Driver("John", "01/01/1980");
drivers.add(d1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you would create a `List<Driver>` (or some other collection, e.g. `Map`) in which to store all the Drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple array:

```
Driver[] drivers = {new Driver("John", "01/01/1980"),
                    new Driver("Smith", "02/02/1990")};

// or

Driver[] drivers = new Driver[2];
drivers[0] = new Driver("John", "01/01/1980");
drivers[1] = new Driver("Smith", "02/02/1990");
```

But array has fixed size once you create it. So, you can use `ArrayList` instead:

```
List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
drivers.add(new Driver("John", "01/01/1980"));
drivers.add(new Driver("Smith", "02/02/1990"));
// ...
```